# How to check if class overides parent methods in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create something like interface in ES6 and I want to force overide methods in base class.

```
class DatabaseAPI {
  login() {
     throw new Error('Unimplemented method: login');
  }
}

class UserService extends DatabaseAPI {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Is there any way to force above error during creating UserService class?

Comment: Maybe be you want to look at Typescript?

Comment: `(new UserService).login()`?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan why?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It supports interfaces in its level, and if the function is not implemented you will get a compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. The error will be thrown once `login` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this package you can try it out
[es6-interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-interface)